# Eloquent How to use (NOT) EXISTS with select subquery

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have a query that looks like below:

```
SELECT      NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT      1
                FROM        seminar_applicants AS sa
                JOIN        seminars AS s
                ON          sa.seminar_id = s.id
                JOIN        schedule_sectors AS b
                ON          b.id = s.schedule_sector_id
                WHERE       sa.user_id = $user_id AND
                            ( a.start_time BETWEEN
                            b.start_time AND b.end_time ) AND
                            a.start_time != b.end_time
            ) AS applicable
FROM        seminars
JOIN        schedule_sectors AS a
ON          seminars.schedule_sector_id = a.id
WHERE       seminars.id = $seminar_id;
```

This essentially checks for collisions in datetime timestamps of seminars for an applicant to apply. applicable should return true/1 if there are no collisions ( the start time of the seminar the user applies to doesn't coincide with another seminar the user has previously registered ).

`$seminar_id` and `$user_id` are placeholders for their respective inputs. I'm stuck trying to find the correct syntax for `NOT EXISTS` select subquery. While I could just use the raw-query but, I would prefer to stick to eloquent because I have no clue how to protect against vulnerabilities.

as an added question, can I know if the `BETWEEN` mysql comparison operator also have a corresponding eloquent method?